# how to filter a list using an array of options

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to filter a list by passing an array of options into a field that is also an array

```
let myFilters = ['filter1', 'filter4'];

let myArray = [
  { name: 'item1', options: ['filter1', 'filter5'] },
  { name: 'item2', options: ['filter1', 'filter2'] }
];

let myResultFiltered = myArray.filter(item => 
myFilters.includes(item.options))
```

Comment: Whats the desire output ?

Comment: Should the options meet all filters or is it enough to just meet a single one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
let myFilters = ['filter1', 'filter4'];

let myArray = [
  { name: 'item1', options: ['filter1', 'filter5'] },  // OUTPUT FOR: OR
  { name: 'item2', options: ['filter1', 'filter2'] },  // OUTPUT FOR: OR
  { name: 'item3', options: ['filter1', 'filter4'] },  // OUTPUT FOR: OR, AND
  { name: 'item4', options: ['filter2', 'filter3'] }   // OUTPUT FOR: NONE
];

// Includes each entry that fulfills AT LEAST ONE of the filter options
let myResultFilteredOR = myArray
   .filter(item => myFilters
      .some(myFilter=> item.options            // any ONE filter
         .some(option => option === myFilter)  // is AT LEAST ONCE in options
      )
   );

// Includes each entry that fulfills ALL of the filter options
let myResultFilteredAND = myArray
   .filter(item => myFilters   
      .every(myFilter=> item.options           // EVERY filter
         .some(option => option === myFilter)  // is AT LEAST ONCE in Options
      )
   );
```

Comment: Wow, it worked perfectly! thank you friend I've tried a few things here but with no success. Now I learned about two new things in JS some() and every() thank you @pascalpuetz !!